# Unable to parse some UTF-8 characters in a txt file uploaded from Spring POST Method

Tags: string, parsing, spring-boot, utf-8, spring-restcontroller

I have been trying to make a string validator but some characters in the input have some swedish characters which I haven't been able to parse. I have been going mad about this. Tried everything I found on the internet. Can anybody please help me out?

This is the logic for reading the file. I have been trying to parse it.

I haven't been able to specifically parse this word: leverantör. It's parsed as leverant�r.

```
public String processFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException, FormatNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
    String output;
    while((output = r.readLine())!=null ) {
        logger.debug(output);
        InputStream is= new ByteArrayInputStream(output.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
         StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           try (
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                                (is, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
               int c = 0;
               while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                   textBuilder.append((char) c);
               }
           } 
           logger.debug(textBuilder.toString());
           System.out.println(textBuilder.toString());
    }
    return "File read.";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parse", exactly? Parse it into what? If you mean that you want to divide it into individual utf-8 code sequences, then it's a bit odd to start by turning the input into bytes.

Comment: � is a silent signal to your users that you've lost their data due to a mojibake bug. You have to start with knowing which character encoding the text file is encoded with. If only the users know then either make them tell you or tell them which single encoding you accept.